# Retrieving json data and displaying

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I am facing some issue in displaying the json data dynamically. I have more than 80 rows of data. When I am trying to display the name dynamically all the names are becoming the same. ie, it is taking the last data in the list

```js
$(".mem-wrap").each(function(){
 var url ="welcome/fetchdata";
 var mm = $(this).parent().attr('data-id');

 $.ajax({
 url: url,
 data: "id="+mm,
     context: document.body
 }).done(function(data) {
  var data3 = JSON.parse(data);
  console.log(mm+"  "+"  "+data3.results[0].name);
  console.log($(this).find('.name').html());
  $(this).find('.name').text(data3.results[0].name);
       

 });
});
```

```html
<div class="team-wrap-2" data-id="2" > 
  <img src="images.." alt="" />
                <div class="mem-wrap">
                  <div class="mem-name-wrap">
                    <h2 class="name">abcd</h2>
                    <h3 class="des">sfgh</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="team-wrap-2" data-id="3" > 
                <img src="images/team/...." alt="" />
                <div class="mem-wrap">
                  <div class="mem-name-wrap">
                    <h2 class="name"></h2>
                    <h3 class="des"></h3>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="team-wrap-2" data-id="4" > <img src="images/team/thumb/mem.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="mem-wrap">
                  <div class="mem-name-wrap">
                    <h2 class="name">fdg</h2>
                    <h3 class="des">sfdsf</h3>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
              </div>
```

Comment: where is `for` loop to traverse all 80 data present in `data3`?

Comment: You are directly attaching without traversing with loop `$(this).find('.name').text(data3.results[0].name);`  change it with for loop

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a for loop. like this :

```
$(".mem-wrap").each(function(){
var url ="welcome/fetchdata";
var mm = $(this).parent().attr('data-id');

$.ajax({
url: url,
data: "id="+mm,
 context: document.body
}).done(function(data) {
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){

   } 
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not iterating the result set index.

Try this

```js
   
    $(".mem-wrap").each(function(){
         var url ="welcome/fetchdata";
         var mm = $(this).parent().attr('data-id');
            
         $.ajax({
         url: url,
         data: "id="+mm,
             context: document.body
         }).done(function(data) {
               for(var i=0 ;i<data.length;i++){
          var data3 = JSON.parse(data);
          console.log(mm+"  "+"  "+data3.results[i].name);
          console.log($(this).find('.name').html());
          $(this).find('.name').text(data3.results[i].name);
             }
               

         });
        });
```

```html
    <div class="team-wrap-2" data-id="2" > 
          <img src="images.." alt="" />
                        <div class="mem-wrap">
                          <div class="mem-name-wrap">
                            <h2 class="name">abcd</h2>
                            <h3 class="des">sfgh</h3>
                          </div>
                          <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="team-wrap-2" data-id="3" > 
                        <img src="images/team/...." alt="" />
                        <div class="mem-wrap">
                          <div class="mem-name-wrap">
                            <h2 class="name"></h2>
                            <h3 class="des"></h3>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="team-wrap-2" data-id="4" > <img src="images/team/thumb/mem.jpg" alt="" />
                        <div class="mem-wrap">
                          <div class="mem-name-wrap">
                            <h2 class="name">fdg</h2>
                            <h3 class="des">sfdsf</h3>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                      </div>
```

Comment: based on your json data check which one is array and loop on that object